# MongoDB 3.6 - Updating using ArrayFilters

Tags: arrays, mongodb

I've this structure....

```
{
  "_id":ObjectId(5a91b66f847ef11bd6e46a3b),
   "socialCores":[
   {
     "name":"Family",
     "uuid":"d40be8a3-0e1e-483b-9e14-8ec2b87126c5",
     "users":[
        {
           "uuid":"7a6ffaf9-75dc-452d-a96a-963fd4eb2659",
           "username":"@yellowtiger277",
           "bio":"",
           "status":"active",
           "type":"user",
           "isTest":true,
           "name":{
              "title":"mrs",
              "first":"bella",
              "last":"martin",
              "displayName":"martin"
           }
        },
        {
           "uuid":"74e67fc0-bbfa-42c9-a034-99bb396fbb83",
           "username":"@lazyfish811",
           "bio":"",
           "status":"active",
           "type":"user",
           "isTest":true,
           "name":{
              "title":"ms",
              "first":"دینا",
              "last":"احمدی",
              "displayName":"دینا"
           }
        },
        {
           "uuid":"15c70b1a-ea28-4ddd-93d5-c4e8250257e7",
           "username":"@lazyduck718",
           "bio":"",
           "status":"active",
           "type":"user",
           "isTest":true,
           "name":{
              "title":"mr",
              "first":"This is the user to be updated !!!!",
              "last":"orbay",
              "displayName":"orbay"
           }
        }
     ]
  },
  {
     "name":"Hood",
     "uuid":"bad168ea-7eef-4bcc-93dc-6352d5281a2b",
     "users":[
        {
           "uuid":"15c70b1a-ea28-4ddd-93d5-c4e8250257e7",
           "username":"@lazyduck718",
           "bio":"",
           "status":"active",
           "type":"user",
           "isTest":true,
           "name":{
              "title":"mr",
              "first":"babür",
              "last":"orbay",
              "displayName":"scary"
           }
        }
     ]
   }
 ]
}
```

I am trying to update few fields the 3rd index of the 1st socialCore using just the uuid of the user : 15c70b1a-ea28-4ddd-93d5-c4e8250257e7

This is not working...

```
db.getCollection('users').update( {} , { 
  '$set': { 
     'socialCores.$[].users.$[user].username': '@bogus', 
     'socialCores.$[].users.$[user].bio': 'My Bio2 !', 
     'socialCores.$[].users.$[user].title': 'Mr.', 
     'socialCores.$[].users.$[user].first': 'Angus', 
     'socialCores.$[].users.$[user].last': 'Young', 
     'socialCores.$[].users.$[user].displayName': 'Angus from AC/DC' 
   } 
}, 
{ 
   arrayFilters:[ 
       { 
          'user.uuid': '15c70b1a-ea28-4ddd-93d5-c4e8250257e7' 
       }
   ] 
})
```

This is throwing me : No array filter found for identifier 'user' in path 'socialCores.$[].users.$[user].username'

What I am doing wrong ? What is the correct way to archive this ?

Comment: Could you paste the output of db.version() ? Your code works correctly on my machine (3.6.0)

Comment: Sure !I Just updated today :) > db.version()
3.6.3
> Running in a mac OS High Sierra. Attempted using the shell and the robo 3T

Comment: There is something similar reported for 3.6.2 here: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-33442?jql=text%20~%20%22No%20array%20filter%20found%20for%20identifier%22

Comment: @mickl if I downgrade to your version...this will work ?

Comment: Isn't there an ambiguity between socialCores.users.uuid and socialCores.uuid?

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in the comment, the **users uuid** is different from the **socialCores uuid**.

The below modified code inserts rather than updating:

```
'$set': { 
     'users.username': '@bogus', 
     'users.bio': 'My Bio2 !', 
     'users.**name**.title': 'Mr.', 
     'users.**name**.first': 'Angus', 
     'users.**name**.last': 'Young', 
     'users.**name**.displayName': 'Angus from AC/DC' 
   } 
}, 
{ 
   arrayFilters:[ 
       { 
          'users.uuid': '15c70b1a-ea28-4ddd-93d5-c4e8250257e7' 
       }
   ]
```

[image]
so there is something wrong in your schema.

The mocha test result below shows the usage of both the uuid with different results:

[image]

Comment: Social Core have his own uuid just like users. UUID for social cores to identify the social core. and uuid for the users to identify the users.

Comment: But as I said..I don't want to insert a new one..I need to update the target: The user id 15c70b1a-ea28-4ddd-93d5-c4e8250257e7

Comment: I will try once more with $[elem] in arrayFilters and post the results by today or tomorrow.

Comment: It looks like the 3.6 version of mongodb supports arrayfilters and 3.6 supports Win os x64 version only! I tried by updating the node version of the mongodb native library but it still doesn't work because the mongodb runs on a 32 bit os. Has it worked for you?

Comment: update: ie. I have the mongodb 3.0.x version that doesn't support arrayFilters

Comment: No problem! Solving problems on SO help hone my skills. If possible update on the solution that you found.